# Boost for Windows Phone 8?

Tags: boost, windows-phone-8

Are there any boost binaries available for Windows Phone 8? I'm mostly looking for the basic stuff such as `shared_ptr` and threading. Note that threading needs both to be build for ARM and use the correct platform calls, while `shared_ptr` works right of the bat.

If not, how do I build `boost::thread` for Windows Phone 8?

**Update:** I checked out the WinRT API and the boost source. The windows threading in boost relies heavily on Thread Local Storage (TLS), but this is not supported on WinRT. However, there seems to be some Fiber Local Storage (FLS), but it's not quite the same thing.

Comment: Why not use `std::shared_ptr` and `std::thread`?

Comment: In the end I actually did. It was alot of trouble though as I had to patch the entire third-party library.

Comment: This update was very useful. TLS is not supported in WinRT or WinPRT. IMO, we need to start making the distinction between the runtimes. In this case it's the same difference, but not in all cases (ex: winsock).

Comment: You can use Fiber Local Storage instead of TLS. Signatures are pretty much the same and achieve the same thing

Comment: @dotMorten yeah, great comment. I went down that route first, but realized switching to `std::thread` was faster.

Comment: I successfully replace the TLS bits with FLS. Works the same way for me, and the port was pretty straight forward since signatures are more or less the same for the important pieces.

Answer (score 1):

There is an [official page on this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/07/18/using-boost-libraries-in-windows-store-and-phone-applications.aspx) dated of 18 Jul 2014, confirming that *some of the libraries in Boost use APIs that aren’t available in Windows Store and Phone applications*, and as so saying *We’ve made improvements to the Boost build system to support targeting the Windows Runtime for Windows Store and Phone*.

Answer (score 0):

I'm compiling against some static libraries that rely on boost so I don't think that's an issue at all.

Comment: yes, some parts of boost work fine while others obviously cannot. For example threading needs to link in some binaries. On Windows Phone 8 we need ARM binaries that use the Windows system calls for threading...

Comment: I rely solely on C++11 threading which is supported by almost all compilers and platforms today. Compiling boost for arm didn't seem like an issue (I wasn't the one on our team doing that work - I just build/consume it - but it wasn't my impression boost needed any work whatsoever for compiling to ARM). Actually looking at our WinRT branch that part is no different than the original branch.

Comment: alright, so you build boost your self if I understand it correctly. How  do I build it for Windows Phone 8? If I run bjam it builds for my windows desktop... See more information here: http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/doc/html/bbv2/jam.html

Answer (score 0):

As of Visual Studio 2013 Update 4, you can compile source that uses the [`TLS` APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686801(v=vs.85).aspx) since they are implemented as inlines that forward to the [`FLS` APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682664(v=vs.85).aspx) (which are Store-compliant). Obviously pre-compiled binaries won't work since they will try and bind to `TLS` directly.

FYI the reason `TLS` is deprecated / banned is because there is the potential to leak memory if a thread terminates. If you use `TLS` APIs in Store apps they will have the same issue of potential memory leaks (the [`FlsCallback`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682665(v=vs.85).aspx) provided to [`FlsAlloc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682664(v=vs.85).aspx) is `null`) so consider moving to `TLS` and providing a cleanup function.