# How to build boost::thread for WinRT ARM?

Tags: c++, boost, windows-runtime, arm, boost-thread

Is it possible to use **boost**'s **thread** library on **WinRT** on an **ARM** device? I built the boost library with the bootstrap command line utility, but that built **x86** binaries. I tried to specify ARM with using

```
b2 --with-thread architecture=arm
```

But that gives me lots of errors.

Then I tried to create a static lib project in VS2012, add the thread source files to it and compile to ARM, but I get compile errors like

```
error C2065: 'TLS_OUT_OF_INDEXES' : undeclared identifier
```

I have found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14666476/boost-for-windows-phone-8) that TLS is not supported by WinRT, so that's why I'm getting the compile errors I guess.

Does that mean that the x86 binary built by bootstrap uses the same illegal APIs, so my app wouldn't pass the Windows Store certification anyway?

Is there some way to get around this limitation and build the boost::thread for WinRT ARM? (By the way I don't need the whole threading functionality, only shared_mutex and upgrade_lock.)

Comment: WHy do you need to use Boost specifically?  I am sure the OS provide the same functionality through other API?

Comment: I want to develop a cross-platform multithreaded code base for WinRT, iOS and Android. Since then I decided to use std::thread instead on WinRT and iOS, and it will be replace by boost::thread on Android (since there is not thread support in the std of the current version of NDK on Android).